# Cronjobs delete file issue

Tags: php, cron, delete-file

I have a php file to delete day old images from the server and update the database every hour

```
$downloadDeleteQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE timeleft < 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($downloadDelete = mysql_fetch_array($downloadDeleteQuery)){

$name = $downloadDelete['name'];

$myFile = "../watermarked/".$name;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("");
fclose($fh);
unlink($myFile);

}
```

That is the code to delete the files from the server. This file is run as a cronjob and works every hour editing the database but it doesn't delete the files, but when you go to the file directly http://www... etc it works as intend. Is this a permission error or something else?

Thanks

Comment: What user is used to run cron? log in as that user and try running your script with its permissions. Also as you've been told, better to use the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the full path, I have had to deal with this before as well. Instead of `$myFile = "../watermarked/".$name;` try `$myFile = "/home/user/path/to/watermarked/".$name;`

This will allow to system to see it since the crons are executed by the system. It doesn't initially take the location of the executed files into account.

Comment: Thank you with a bit of fiddling I have it working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a quick comment, It's working kind of intended but it leaves the file there with FileSize being 0?

Comment: Try using the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to pass `rm -f /file/path/and/name` This will make sure that the system deletes in instead of just emptying it's contents.

Comment: You can use the [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete files as well.

Answer (score 1):

Files run by cron have different permissions than ones run by the http server